# Converting pytorch map style dataset to iterable dataset with multi process data loading

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, generator, pytorch-dataloader

I have implemented the following pytorch `map style` dataset. I am wondering how to convert it equivalent `IterableDataset` to yield data.

I read that iterable dataset can be used where random read are expensive and can be used for streaming data.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#iterable-style-datasets

It is also says in documentation to configure correctly for multiprocessing to avoid duplicating data.

I am unable find much example on this. **How can I convert it to IterableDataset properly?**

##### Minimal Dataset

```
class VisionTransformerDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(
            self,
            root_dir: str,
            image_size: int,
            image_channels: int,
    ) -> None:
        super(VisionTransformerDataset, self).__init__()
        _class_list = os.listdir(root_dir)


        self.image_labels_files_list = list()
        for idx, class_name_folder in enumerate(_class_list):
            class_path = os.path.join(root_dir, class_name_folder)
            files_list = os.listdir(class_path)
            for image_file in files_list:
                self.image_labels_files_list.append(
                    (
                        os.path.join(class_path, image_file),
                        idx,
                    )
                )

        self.image_files_list_len = len(self.image_labels_files_list)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.image_files_list_len

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> Tuple[Image.Image, int]:
        image_path, class_label = self.image_labels_files_list[idx]
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        return image, class_label
```

##### Minimal Dataloader

```
vit_dataset = VisionTransformerDataset(
    root_dir=dataset_path,
    image_channels=image_channels,
    image_size=image_size,
)

self.train_loader = DataLoader(
    dataset=vit_dataset,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=num_workers,
    pin_memory=True,
    drop_last=True,
)
```

Comment: You can always use map-style dataset. Iterative-style dataset is designed for a special case if all dataset can not fit into memory. However, in map-style dataset you dont need to load all the data during initialization as well. I have never felt a requirement to use iterative-style dataset.

Comment: @alercelik you cannot use a map-style dataset in concert in a 'Chain', which only accepts IterableDataset objects.  Thus this question of how to convert is a good one. So far my own attempts at adding an __iter__ method calls a __getitem__ method have not worked. Disappointed there's no answer to this question yet.

Comment: Is there any reason why this doesn't work? `dataset[i] for i in range(len(dataset))`, where `dataset` is a map-style dataset